# Run classmethod functions asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await

I have a `class` which grabs the name of the current working directory, and a `@classmethod` that will read files from that directory asynchronously.

For example (template of my script):

```
class testMethod:
    def __init__(self, path): 
        self._path = path

    def getFile(self):
        file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), self._path)
        return file

    @classmethod
    async def asyncFile(cls, type: str = 'json', *args, **kwargs):
        super(cls).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        async def param():
            if type == 'json':
                js_file = cls('args.json').getFile()
                async with aiofiles.open(js_file, 'r') as f:
                    params = json.load( await f)
                return params
        def run():
            return self.run_until_complete(param())
        return run()
```

I get the following:

> <coroutine object testMethod.asyncFile at 0x7fc1b8ffa5c0>
> sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'testMethod.asyncFile' was never awaited

I know this error comes from not awaiting in the correct way, or a loop not properly working. Therefore, what am I missing?

Expected output:

```
b = testMethod('some_path.json').asyncFile()
print(b)

...
<some json content>
...
```

Comment: Since you know that you should be awaiting this but don’t - what exactly are you asking? Have you tried awaiting it?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi At which part? I have awaited it only where it was asynchronous at opening the file

Comment: At asyncFile itself, since it is async.

Comment: Did you mean to define `def asyncFile` instead of `async def asyncFile`?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have tested this before but an alternative error appears. Although that would make sense as no `await` is being used within the function.

Answer (score 0):

The coroutine will not complete the loop when I return the reactor within the same function as the `@classmethod`, therefore, I had to create a separate function to run this in.

Perhaps this is the only way, or there is some method of including `asyncio.run()` wthin `asyncFile`?

```
class testMethod:
    def __init__(self, path): 
        self._path = path
        #self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def getFile(self):
        file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), self._path)
        return file

    @classmethod
    async def asyncFile(cls, type: str = 'json', *args, **kwargs):
        super(cls).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if type == 'json':
            js_file = cls('args.json').getFile()
            print(js_file)
            async with aiofiles.open(js_file, 'r') as f:
                k = await f.read()
                print(yaml.safe_load(k))

    def run(self):
        return asyncio.run(self.asyncFile())

b = testMethod('some_path.json')
b.run()
```

Results:

```
{'path_or_buf': '', 'orient': '', 'typ': '', 'dtype': '', 'convert_axes': '', 'convert_dates': '', 'keep_default_dates': '', 'numpy': '', 'precise_float': '', 'date_unit': '', 'encoding': '', 'encoding_errors': '', 'lines': '', 'chunksize': '', 'compression': '', 'nrows': '', 'storage_options': ''}
```